# Is multiplexer a multipler or adder?

Tags: multiplexer

I'm new to electronics, just learning about logic gates and combinations like binary adders and multipliers. But I came across the internet and found that a simple multiplexer (MUX) could do addition, even multiply-accumulate operations from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer). I'm confused, how choosing 1 and 0 can do the math, isn't it an adder and multiplier that do the math?

Comment: Could you add the link to the Wikipedia page or any other website you found to the question?

Comment: The multiplexer does the logical operations that it does. It is us who deem those operations to be logic, or addition, or multiplication, by choosing how we view the collections of bits going in and out.

Comment: There seems to be a letter missing from the title. On a conversation platform like [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=electronics.stackexchange.com), to invite to-the-point conversations, naming the source ([en.]wikipedia) is a start. Extend that to a full hyperlink, possibly quoting the verbiage you are referring to. Here, [ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and keep an open mind about answers.

Comment: (`a simple multiplexer (MUX) could do [anything]` just like a NOR gate. Or any other circuit called [*universal*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) for this.)

Comment: Sorry, here is the link that I refer to, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer, refer to the last section.

Comment: @DexterLim Which is the last section you mean? The last section is "External Links".

Comment: My bad, the "Unconventional use of Multiplexers for arithmetic" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section that you're referring to ("Unconventional use of Multiplexers for arithmetic") has only been added to the Wikipedia page two days ago. It contains many grammatical errors and cites a source that is almost as young as the edit itself (from March 4th), which makes me suspect that the poor-quality Wikipedia edit was done by one of the paper's authors to boost the reach of their paper. Take it with more than just a grain of salt. For the purpose of learning digital logic, you can disregard the entire section as it's only relevant to the field of statistical computing.

In general, multiplexers can be used to implement any arbitrary logic function. In the simplest case, you can build a look-up table that contains the truth table of the desired logic function directly by connecting each mux input to a constant 1 or 0. The inputs of the circuit are then connected to the select input of the mux. This is also explained in [the "Multiplexers as PLDs" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer#Multiplexers_as_PLDs) of the same Wikipedia article.

Comment: I see, so I better refer to my textbook for now right?

Comment: @DexterLim The Wikipedia page is generally quite good, except for that hastily added last section. But yes, sticking to the textbook is probably a good idea.